# How to assign unique id to user so that if it's already assigned try to assign id + 1

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, set

User chooses id he wants and if it was already assigned to another user then assign minimal free id that is greater than chosen.

User can be deleted and it makes id to be usable again.

I thought it's enough to use HashSet since it's access complexity is O(1) and I just check every greater entry by using contains method.
But in cases like 20000 first IDs assigned and then 20000 new users try to use id 1 HashSet has really slow performance.

What can I do to improve performance? Is there special data structure for such cases?

Comment: Is there an upper bound on ids?

Comment: @Ryan bounds are [1; 10^9]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know it when I asked the question but it's a task from SPOJ: [BLUNIQ](http://www.spoj.com/problems/BLUNIQ/)

I've solved it by using a range structure and TreeSet to store ranges. So initial idea to use search tree was good I just needed to store numbers in ranges and manage them properly. TreeSet has useful methods such as floor (lower or equal) and higher so complexity of search for two nearest ranges (left side and right side) is O(logN).

Both answers from [Petar Petrovic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7433927/petar-petrovic) and [Whatever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6749481/whatever) are OK but they would give Time Limit Exceeded error without specific data structure.

I haven't read any solutions for this task so there could be even faster solution.

```java
static class Range implements Comparable<Range> {
    int leftBound;
    int rightBound;

    public Range(int leftBound, int rightBound) {
        this.leftBound = leftBound;
        this.rightBound = rightBound;
    }

    public void remove(int x) {
        if (x == leftBound) leftBound++; else
        if (x == rightBound) rightBound--; else {
            ranges.remove(this);
            ranges.add(new Range(leftBound, x - 1));
            ranges.add(new Range(x + 1, rightBound));
        }
        if (size() <= 0) ranges.remove(this);
    }

    public long size() {
        return rightBound - leftBound + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Range range) {
        return Long.compare(rightBound, range.rightBound);
    }

    public boolean contains(int x) {
        return leftBound <=x && x <= rightBound;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + leftBound + "; " + rightBound + "]";
    }

}

static public void add(int x) {

    Range singleRange = new Range(x, x);
    Range lowerOrEqual = ranges.floor(singleRange);
    Range higher = ranges.higher(singleRange);
    if ((lowerOrEqual == null || lowerOrEqual.rightBound + 1 < x) && (higher == null || higher.leftBound - 1 > x)) {
        System.out.println(x);
        ranges.add(singleRange);
    } else {

        if (lowerOrEqual != null && (lowerOrEqual.rightBound == x || lowerOrEqual.rightBound + 1 == x)) {
            System.out.println(++lowerOrEqual.rightBound);
            if (higher != null && lowerOrEqual.rightBound == higher.leftBound - 1) {
                Range merged = new Range(lowerOrEqual.leftBound, higher.rightBound);
                ranges.remove(lowerOrEqual);
                ranges.remove(higher);
                ranges.add(merged);
            }
        } else if (higher != null && higher.leftBound - 1 == x) {
            System.out.println(--higher.leftBound);
            if (lowerOrEqual != null && lowerOrEqual.rightBound == higher.leftBound - 1) {
                Range merged = new Range(lowerOrEqual.leftBound, higher.rightBound);
                ranges.remove(lowerOrEqual);
                ranges.remove(higher);
                ranges.add(merged);
            }
        } else if (higher != null && higher.contains(x)) {
            System.out.println(++higher.rightBound);
            Range higherThanHigher = ranges.higher(higher);
            if (higherThanHigher != null && higher.rightBound + 1 == higherThanHigher.leftBound) {
                Range merged = new Range(higher.leftBound, higherThanHigher.rightBound);
                ranges.remove(higher);
                ranges.remove(higherThanHigher);
                ranges.add(merged);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and how it was used:

```java
private static TreeSet<Range> ranges = new TreeSet<>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    int N = Integer.parseInt(bufferRead.readLine());

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        String[] strings = bufferRead.readLine().split(" ");
        int[] event = {Integer.parseInt(strings[0]), Integer.parseInt(strings[1])};

        if (event[0] == 1) {
            add(event[1]);
        } else {
            Range singleRange = new Range(event[1], event[1]);
            Range lowerOrEqual = ranges.floor(singleRange);
            Range higher = ranges.higher(singleRange);
            if (lowerOrEqual != null && lowerOrEqual.rightBound == event[1]) {
                lowerOrEqual.remove(event[1]);
            } else if (higher != null && higher.leftBound <= event[1]) {
                higher.remove(event[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a search tree (or something similar)! Binary tree is one of the simplest types of search trees, but its main disadvantage is that it is not balanced and might be slower than the self-balancing trees, such as the red-black tree.

Of course, you won't have `O(1)` time complexity (I doubt there is an algorithm which is able to find, remove and add in `O(1)`), but you will have `O(lg n)` (in case of the slowest trees) or amortized `O(1)` (for the best trees) time complexity for insertion and removal (with look up)(time complexity is tree specific).

Comment: I don't really see the way how I can use priority queue. I should assign min id that is greater that user chose. Not just min of available. Or I don't know something about priority queue? Iteration over PQ to find such id will be really slow. Isn't it?

Comment: my idea is to store ranges of taken ids somehow and split them if delete of id happened inside. And also somehow make fast search over them to find nearest free position.

Comment: @Awethon I guess you won't be able to find a free id quickly using this approach. And splitting is usually a bad idea. You need a structure that supports such operation, e.g. linked list, but such structures do not support random access, which means you have to iterate = slow

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a binary search tree to store unused id.

Binary search tree support finding the smallest item that is greater than input item in O(log n) time. (n is number of items in trees)

Some languages have already implemented this. For example upper_bound[1] for set in cpp or higher[2] for TreeSet in java.

1. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/upper_bound
2. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#higher(E)